# How to convert a spatial dataframe back to normal dataframe?

Tags: r, type-conversion, dataframe, spatial

This is a basic question but unfortunately I could not find the relevant command elsewhere.

Is there a way i can convert a Spatial Points Dataframe to an ordinary dataframe in R.

e.g. if the ordinary dataframe is `df` with Lat, Lon as location coordinates I can obtain a spatial df as:

```
coordinates (df)= ~Lat + Lon
```

How is the reverse possible or is it even possible ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`as.data.frame()` does just what you are looking for:

```
library(sp)
# Construct a SpatialPointsDataFrame
data(meuse)
xy <- meuse[1:2]
df <- meuse[-1:-2]
SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=df)

# And then convert it (back) to a data.frame
DF <- as.data.frame(SPDF)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I convert xy from SpatialCoordinates to standard values in degrees?

Comment: That'll of course depend on the [coordinate reference system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) of the x-y coordinates. In general, though, you can use `sp:spTransform()`. Here is [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18641016/980833); although it happens to be going in the opposite direction (i.e. transforming away from long-lat), the idea is the same.

Comment: and how can I make it reverse? I tried switching the values in CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"), it doesn't work.

Comment: That should work if you've got a `SpatialPoints`  object (for instance) with a proper CRS. (You can see that it  does work by running the example given in the answer I linked just above and then doing `spTransform(res, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))` to  successfully reverse the transformation. Since this isn't working on your data, it must be a problem with your `Spatial*` object rather than with the `spTransform()` command. Cheers.

Comment: I could start from the example and converting back and forth. The problem is that when I want to start from NAD83 State Plane Coordinates, it doesn't work. I tried this: xy <- data.frame(ID = 1, X = c(577430), Y = c(2323270))
coordinates(xy) <- c("X", "Y")
proj4string(xy) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")  ##
res <- spTransform(xy, CRS("+proj=utm +zone=51  ellps=WGS84")). Please see more details on what I stuck in [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499999/converting-nad83-state-plane-coordinates-to-ws84-standard-lon-lat-in-degrees/39500834#39500834).