# R transforming coordinates inside the data.frame

Tags: r, coordinates, spatial

Converting coordinates in R is straightforward with spTransform etc, but is there a way to bypass the Spatial object and convert directly in the dataframe? To just run the transformation equation on 2 columns? E.g. from latlon to British National Grid as new columns:

```
# current way using a spatial object
require(raster)
require(rgdal)

# define BNG and latlon
BNG <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
LL <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")

# dummy data
toconv <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c"), lat=c(54.530776,54.551913,54.455268), lon=c(-2.6006958,-2.4084351,-2.4688599))

# promote to spatial points data frame and define CRS of points
coordinates(toconv) = ~lon + lat
crs(toconv) <- LL

# current LL coordinates as columns in the SPDF
toconv$Xlon <- coordinates(toconv)[,1]
toconv$Ylat <- coordinates(toconv)[,2]

# transform to BNG
conv <- spTransform(toconv, crs(BNG))

# rename the coords from original name to new wanted name
colnames(conv@coords) <- c("Xbng","Ybng")

# extract as data frame, new coords with new name are new columns. 
final <- as.data.frame(conv)
```

However i want to go from the original dummy data ('toconv') straight to the final output ('final') without faffing around, is is possible in one function? (e.g. a function containing the Helmert Transformation or OSTN02 Transformation)

Comment: so you would like one line of code to do all this stuff instead of several lines?

Comment: yes, i thought there would be a function to do this without the spatial object

Comment: i think the answer is `gdalUtils::gdaltransform` but i'm getting status 1 and NAs at the moment, i'll continue to explore

Answer (score 1):

I messed around quite a lot for answering your question.

I understood that you are looking for a straightforward function to transform coordinates between different projections.

The desired final output is:

```
  id      Xlon     Ylat     Xbng     Ybng
1  a -2.600696 54.53078 361224.2 515221.4
2  b -2.408435 54.55191 373679.8 517484.1
3  c -2.468860 54.45527 369699.8 506754.6
```

I tried several approaches using both packages `proj4` and the one you named in your comment. Unfortunately, the results were different than those obtained using the brilliant `sp` packages created by Dr. Pebesma.

Therefore, my final solution to your question is to create a function named `help_sam` that make straightforward for you to change the coordinate reference system of data.frame structured as `toconv`.

```
BNG <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")
LL <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
toconv <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","c"), lat=c(54.530776,54.551913,54.455268), lon=c(-2.6006958,-2.4084351,-2.4688599))



help_sam = function(data,
                    src.proj = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"),
                    dst.proj = CRS("+init=epsg:27700")) {
        require(sp)
        as.data.frame(
                spTransform(
                        SpatialPointsDataFrame(
                                coords = data.frame(Xbng = toconv$lon,
                                                    Ybng = toconv$lat),
                                data = data.frame(id = toconv$id,
                                                  Xlon = toconv$lon,
                                                  Ylat = toconv$lat),
                                proj4string = src.proj), dst.proj))

}
final <- help_sam(data = toconv)
print(final)

  id      Xlon     Ylat     Xbng     Ybng
1  a -2.600696 54.53078 361224.2 515221.4
2  b -2.408435 54.55191 373679.8 517484.1
3  c -2.468860 54.45527 369699.8 506754.6
```

If you want to change the `CRS` of the final projection you just have to set a different `espg` value for parameter `dst.proj` in function `help_sam()`.

Comment: Seymour, thanks. What I am wondering - and can change my qu - is if there is a specific function (or other) that directly works with numeric class columns and performs the mathematical transformation without faffing around with a spatial object

Comment: yours works thanks, and is just a condensed version of mine, but considering transformations are just equations, i thought there would be a function that did this to a column of numbers. Perhaps i'll just write one.

Comment: If this answer to this question please validate my answer

Comment: it is not the answer i am looking for, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function that does this with data.table, sf and rgdal.

```r
## Packages
library(sf)
library(data.table)
library(rgdal)


## Data
# Example data from question

# Note: using a data.table instead of a data.frame here
#       so we can use the function below to add new projected columns
toconv <-
    data.table(
        id = c("a", "b", "c"),
        lat = c(54.530776, 54.551913, 54.455268),
        lon = c(-2.6006958, -2.4084351, -2.4688599)
    )


## Function
# Project coordinates inside a data.table within converting to a spatial object
# Uses rgdal::project a matrix of geographical positions to projected coordinates
# Expectated order: X coordinate, Y coordinate
project_coords <- function(DT, coords, projection, projcoords) {
    DT[, (projcoords) :=
            data.table::as.data.table(
                rgdal::project(
                    as.matrix(.SD, ncol = 2),
                    projection)
            ),
         .SDcols = coords][]
}


# Useful checks to add:
#   Are the columns named in coords numeric?
#   Is the projection a character?
#   Is it a valid projection?
#   Are the coord1inates in the right order?

## Usage
# Setup output CRS (using the sf function st_crs and returning the WKT representation)
projection <- st_crs(27700)$wkt


# Project coordinates
project_coords(
    DT = toconv,
    coords = c('lon', 'lat'),
    projection = projection,
    projcoords = c('Xbng', 'Ybng')
)
#>    id      lat       lon     Xbng     Ybng
#> 1:  a 54.53078 -2.600696 361131.2 515235.4
#> 2:  b 54.55191 -2.408435 373585.3 517497.9
#> 3:  c 54.45527 -2.468860 369605.8 506769.7
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Also note this related question: [Converting latitude and longitude points to UTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm)