# Wrong value occur when converting points from UTM to WGS84 in R

Tags: r, coordinates

I use the method from Stanislav in [this topic of Forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm), which is a question about "converting latitude and longitude points to UTM". I edited the function reversely to change points from UTM to WGS84, which is:

```
library(sp); library(rgdal)

#Function
UTMToLongLat<-function(x,y,zone){
  xy <- data.frame(ID = 1:length(x), X = x, Y = y)
  coordinates(xy) <- c("X", "Y")
  proj4string(xy) <- CRS(paste("+proj=utm +zone=",zone," ellps=WGS84",sep=''))  
  res <- spTransform(xy, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
  return(as.data.frame(res))
}
```

The example in the previous question mentioned above is tried, that is:

```
x2 <- c(-48636.65, 1109577); y2 <- c(213372.05, 5546301)
```

What is expected is (118, 10), (119, 50) in WGS84. Colin's example is in UTM51.

So, the following sentence is used:

```
done2 <- UTMToLongLat(x2,y2,51)
```

However, it produced: (118.0729, 1.92326), (131.4686, 49.75866).

What is wrong? By the way, how to control the decimal digits of the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you mistook the expression of the coordinate. It should be:

```
x <- c(-48636.65, 213372.05)
y <- c(1109577, 5546301)
```

In the function, it will be transformed and stored as:

```
> data.frame(ID = 1:length(x), X = x, Y = y)
#   ID         X       Y
# 1  1 -48636.65 1109577
# 2  2 213372.05 5546301
```

And execute your function again:

```
> UTMToLongLat(x, y, 51)
#   ID   X         Y
# 1  1 118  9.999997
# 2  2 119 50.000001
```

To control the decimal digits:

```
> round(UTMToLongLat(x, y, 51))
#   ID   X  Y
# 1  1 118 10
# 2  2 119 50
```